# Java Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: java

I'm a beginner and pursuing a hyperskill course for java. I tried to attempt [this](https://hyperskill.org/projects/48/stages/259/implement) tic tac toe game project in VS Code. It worked fine. But the code gave errors on submission.

Code:

```
package tictactoe;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static int movesCommitted = 0;
    static String[][][] matrix = {{{" ", "13"}, {" ", "23"}, {" ", "33"}}, 
                                  {{" ", "12"}, {" ", "22"}, {" ", "32"}},
                                  {{" ", "11"}, {" ", "21"}, {" ", "31"}}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean drawCounter = true;
        board(matrix);
        do {
            String symbol = (movesCommitted % 2 == 0) ? "X" : "O";
            validateAndAppend(symbol, scanner);     // Validate for wrong input and filled spots
            board(matrix);    // Display board
            movesCommitted++;
            if (anyWinner(symbol)) {
                drawCounter = false;
                System.out.println(symbol + " wins");
                break;
            }

        } while (movesCommitted < 9);

        if (drawCounter) {
            System.out.println("Draw");
        }
    }

    public static void board(String[][][] arr) {
        System.out.println("---------");
        System.out.println("| " + arr[0][0][0] + " " + arr[0][1][0] + " " + arr[0][2][0] + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + arr[1][0][0] + " " + arr[1][1][0] + " " + arr[1][2][0] + " |");
        System.out.println("| " + arr[2][0][0] + " " + arr[2][1][0] + " " + arr[2][2][0] + " |");
        System.out.println("---------");
    }

    public static void validateAndAppend(String symbol, Scanner scanner) {
        boolean cont = true;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter coordinates: ");
            String inp = scanner.nextLine();  // Input move
            int dataInput;
            String input = "0" + inp;
            input = input.replace(" ", "");
            if (Integer.parseInt(input) < 11) {
                System.out.println("You should enter numbers!");
                continue;
            } else {
                dataInput = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }

            int unit = dataInput % 10;
            int tens = dataInput / 10;

            if (unit < 1 || unit > 3 || tens < 1 || tens > 3) {
                System.out.println("Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!");
                continue;
                // break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (matrix[i][j][1].toString().equals(String.valueOf(dataInput))) {
                        if (matrix[i][j][0] == " ") {
                            matrix[i][j][0] = symbol;
                            cont = false;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("This cell is occupied! Choose another one!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (cont);
    }

    public static Boolean anyWinner(String xo) {
        if (movesCommitted < 5) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            if (matrix[i][0][0] == xo && matrix[i][1][0] == xo && matrix[i][2][0] == xo) {
                return true;    // This is row check
            }

            if (matrix[0][i][0] == xo && matrix[1][i][0] == xo && matrix[2][i][0] == xo) {
                return true;    // This is column check
            }
        }

        if (matrix[0][0][0] == xo && matrix[1][1][0] == xo && matrix[2][2][0] == xo) {
            return true;    // This is "\" diagonal check
        }

        if (matrix[0][2][0] == xo && matrix[1][1][0] == xo && matrix[2][0][0] == xo) {
            return true;    // This is "/" check
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in test #2

Probably your program run out of input (Scanner tried to read more than expected). If you are sure it's not, this type of exception also happens if you created more than one Scanner object (it is preferred to use a single Scanner in program).

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at tictactoe.Main.validateAndAppend(Main.java:44)
    at tictactoe.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

---------
|       |
|       |
|       |
---------
Enter coordinates: >4 1
Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!
Enter coordinates: >3 1
This cell is occupied! Choose another one!
Enter coordinates: >4 4
Coordinates should be from 1 to 3!
Enter coordinates: >2 2
This cell is occupied! Choose another one!
```

The original error is quite long (The inputs). It seems that the error is in the validateAndAppend() method the program doesn't distinguish wrong input from correct one on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the website's input tests are causing a problem scanning `String inp`.

The error you are getting (`java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`) is due to the scanner not finding the next line, so try to check if any line exists before adding the input to `inp` :

```
System.out.print("Enter coordinates: ");

String inp="$";

if(scanner.hasNextLine())    // Check if next line exists
    inp=scanner.nextLine();  // Input move

if(inp.equals("$"))   // If inp did not change show an error and input again
{
    System.out.println("Input error");
    continue;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is another method that could help you :

```
System.out.print("Enter coordinates: ");

String inp=null;
try
{
    inp=scanner.nextLine();
} catch(Exception e)
{
    return;
}

int dataInput;
// rest of you code
```

Comment: I understand but the program now performs an infinite loop and the build fails

Comment: Okay, what if you add `if(!scanner.hasNextLine()) return;` before `String inp=scanner.nextLine();` ? Also please remove any changes made from my previous answer. Just add the line to your original code.

Comment: The error remains same. The only difference is that the code works with no input at the end

Comment: @AnikinSkywalker It's hard to debug since the program works fine except on the submission tests, but I edited my answer and added another method that could fix the problem.

Comment: I guess the fault is in their system. Exception handling is not working. Thank you for the efforts